# Is there a smart solution to transform a DataFrame by a function and set the result to each cell?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

the below is an example:

input:

```
1  2  3 
4  5  6
```

output:

```
2.5 3.5 4.5 
2.5 3.5 4.5
```

here, I want to get each column's `mean` and set the result to each cell in the column.
If I use loop can do the job. I think it's too ugly.
I try to use apply, but I can't get the column information in the function.

is there any smart solution?

Comment: A neat way is `df.loc[:] = df.mean().values`.

Comment: @ajcr, it's a very nice solution, but do you have an idea why if i try to do it for the second time (i.e. literally run `df.loc[:] = df.mean().values` two times) i get `ValueError: cannot set using a slice indexer with a different length than the value` ?

Comment: Hmmm, that's a strange error. I wouldn't have though trying modify the frame again in this way would cause problems. I'll have to study the traceback some more.

Comment: It seems `df.loc[:, :] = df.mean().values` is fine to repeat so looks like pandas gets rows/cols muddled in some way if you're not explicit.

Comment: @ajcr, thank you! It's really a little bit unexpected behavior  with multiple execution of `df.loc[:] = df.mean().values` though

Answer (score 3):

IMO loops solutions (if it's still a vectorized solution) are not always evil.

In order to be fair, all solutions will work on a copy of the original DF:

```
In [32]: %paste
def not_so_ugly(df):
    x = df.copy()
    for col in x.columns:
        x[col] = x[col].mean()
    return x

def apply_mean(df):
    x = df.copy()
    return x.apply(lambda c: np.repeat(c.mean(), len(x)))


def stack_groupby(df):
    x = df.copy()
    return x.stack().groupby(level=1).transform(lambda x: x.mean()).unstack()

def concat_transpose(df):
    x = df.copy()
    new_df = pd.concat([x.mean()]*len(x),axis=1).T
    new_df.index = x.index
    return new_df

## -- End pasted text --
```

Timing:

```
In [37]: df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randint(0, 10**7, size=(10**5, 3)), columns=list('abc'))

In [38]: %timeit concat_transpose(df)
1 loop, best of 3: 1.66 s per loop

In [39]: %timeit stack_groupby(df)
10 loops, best of 3: 153 ms per loop

In [40]: %timeit apply_mean(df)
100 loops, best of 3: 6.65 ms per loop

In [41]: %timeit not_so_ugly(df)
100 loops, best of 3: 5.1 ms per loop
```

Comment: I have try your apply_mean(). but I guess the copy is only for the test purpose. my understand is right?

Comment: @ChandlerSong, yes. You would need `df.apply(lambda c: np.repeat(c.mean(), len(df)))`, but pay attention at `df.loc[:, :] = df.mean().values` solution from ajcr - i think it's the best one...

Comment: I think the apply solution is better too. I test performance, apply is better, it's 2ms quicker than ajcr. and ajcr solution, the copy is must if I want to keep the orgin data. the performance will be much worse for large data I guess. but his solution is much neat.

Answer (score 1):

This hack should work, but I feel there should be even better (meaning not hacky at all)...

```
new_df = pd.concat([df.mean()]*len(df),axis=1).T
new_df.index = df.index
```

Answer (score 0):

This is less hacky but still ugly.

```
df.stack().groupby(level=1).transform(lambda x: x.mean()).unstack()
```